# Call to retrieve byte array from API works for iOS but fails for Android in MAUI app

Tags: android, maui, visual-studio-2022

I have a .NET MAUI app that interfaces with an API and one of the functions of this app is to display documents and images (byte []) retrieved from the API. When running the iOS version of the app, the calls to retrieve the byte array without any problem. However, the exact same call to retrieve the byte array never returns when being called from the Android version of the app. I have searched for any possible solution but cannot find anything that would address this. Has anyone experienced similar behavior and if so, how is it resolved? Can it be a setting in the Android environment that I'm missing?

Comment: please ready [ask] before posting.  Without seeing the relevant code or a more meaningful description of the problem its difficult to help you.  "Never returns" sounds like a connectivity issue and you are just not waiting long enough for a timeout to occur.

Comment: the call being made is this:     var bytes = _documentsAppService.GetDocument(value).Result; which is a call to an asynchronous API call. In iOS, this call executes perfectly but in Android, the call does not return a value and I have waited through 2 timeouts on the Android tablet that I am using. The data that is returned is not a huge amount of data and should return quickly.

Comment: a) please [edit] your question to include additional info, b) `async` calls should use `await`, c) have you verified connectivity to your server from the Android device?

Comment: I don't have much additional information. The call uses the .Result as opposed to using await because it is in an override function that cannot be defined as an async call. Using .Result performs the await and returns the result. I have verified connectivity. I make several other calls to retrieve data prior to the call to get the byte array, and they all succeed with the exception of this call. I have about 5 areas in the program that make calls to retrieve byte arrays and all of them fail when executed in the Android app but succeed in the iOS app.

Comment: This could be a potential issue on Android Maui, consider raise [a new issue](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues) on Github. Alternatively, you may can switch to Android Studio using Java to achieve that function.